# Javascript Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: javascript, html

I followed the tutorial on Javascript on http://www.codecademy.com and one part was to create a rock, paper, scissors game. After I finished it I figured I would redesign it a bit to use on my own. So I did this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
        var userChoice = document.getElementById("userChoice").value;

        if (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors"){
            alert("Your choice was not rock, paper or scissors");
            userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
        }
        var computerChoice = Math.random();
        if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
            computerChoice = "rock";
        } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
            computerChoice = "paper";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "scissors";
        }

        var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
            if (choice1 == choice2) {
                return "The result is a tie!";
            } else if (choice1 == "rock") {
                if (choice2 == "scissors") {
                    return "Rock wins";
                } else {
                    return "Paper wins";
                }
            } else if (choice1 == "paper") {
                if (choice2 == "rock") {
                    return "Paper wins";
                } else {
                    return "Scissors wins";
                }
            } else if (choice1 == "scissors") {
                if (choice2 == "paper") {
                    return "Scissors win";
                } else {
                    return "Rock wins";
                }
            }
        }

        function Run() {
            document.getElementById("pcc").innerHTML = "Computer: " + computerChoice;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
        }
    </script>
    <main>
        <h2>Choose between rock, paper or scissors: </h2>
        <input id="userChoice">
        <button onClick="Run()">Choose</button>
        <p id="pcc"></p>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work, I get undefined for compare, computerChoice, userChoice and that there isn't anything that becomes stored in value.
What's wrong?

Comment: You are trying to access HTML elements before they exist …

Comment: @CBroe Realised that after I posted, but even if I put the script at the bottom it doesn't work...

Comment: You are trying to get the `value` right away, before the user even has a chance to type something into the field. You need to read the value at the time you actually want to use it, only that way you will get the current value of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all of the content of the script in a function, try this. It is trying to use the variables before they are set by the logic at the beginning since the logic at the beginning is never called:)

```
    function run(){  

    var userChoice = document.getElementById("userChoice").value;

    if (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors"){
        alert("Your choice was not rock, paper or scissors");
        userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    }
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }

    var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 == choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";
        } else if (choice1 == "rock") {
            if (choice2 == "scissors") {
                return "Rock wins";
            } else {
                return "Paper wins";
            }
        } else if (choice1 == "paper") {
            if (choice2 == "rock") {
                return "Paper wins";
            } else {
                return "Scissors wins";
            }
        } else if (choice1 == "scissors") {
            if (choice2 == "paper") {
                return "Scissors win";
            } else {
                return "Rock wins";
            }
        }
    }
        document.getElementById("pcc").innerHTML = "Computer: " + computerChoice;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `<main>` tags and correctly close your second paragraph tag like so:

```
<p id="result"></p>
```